# is function print has bug in clojure?

Tags: clojure, macros, eval

I write a macro:

```
(defmacro te
  [a b & c]
  `(print
     ~(a b c)))
```

and run

```
(te print 2 inc 4)
```

got an error `ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/eval8010 (form-init8519408738377285198.clj:1)`

and I run

```
(macroexpand-1 '(te print 2 3 4)
;=> (clojure.core/print (3 4))
```

it means `(print 2 (3 4))` return `(3 4)`? is it function `print` has bug?

My clojure version 1.7.0, JVM version 1.8.0_65-b17

---

update

Ok.the example is not understand easily by commit.

even i run the

```
(te print 2 inc 4)

user=> (te print 2 inc 4)
;=> 5nil

user=> (macroexpand-1 '(te print 2 inc 4))
;=> (clojure.core/print (inc 4))
```

it will print `5` and return `nil`,that mean `(print 2 (inc 4))` return form `(inc 4)`?

Comment: Why is it often assumed that common libraries/frameworks have bugs that aren't reported on the relevant group? :{ Instead, consider this: what does the form `(3 4)` mean in Clojure? (Evaluate it on the REPL -  being the output of the macro is irrelevant.) Why would that result in the reported error? Why does the error remain (and it will) after replacing `print` with something else?

Comment: I know, but i think you don't understand my question mean.in the macro ~(a b c) can retrun a value which not nil ?the `a` is function `print` it will return a form `c` ?

Comment: I think what you want to asked is: since `\`(print ~(inc 2))` will get form `(print 3)`, why `(defmacro print-result [a b] \`(print ~(a b)))` and `(macroexpand-1 '(print-result inc 2))` will get `(print nil)`?

Answer (score 8):

This is not related to `print` at all.

> it means `(print 2 (3 4))` return `(3 4)`?

That's not what it means, and that's the source of your problem. It means "call the function `print` with first argument `2` and second argument the value of `(3 4)`". The expression `(3 4)` has no valid value because it means "call function `3` with argument `4`" which is why you get an exception: 3 is a Long (number) and cannot be called as a function (in clojure internals, it does not implement the IFn function interface).

As a side note, if I understand what you're trying to achieve (I may be wrong) your macro can easily be written as a function, which in general means you should write it as a function, since functions are easier to deal with and work better with other functions.

Comment: `(a 2 (3 4)` actually does return `(3 4)`, though, where the value of `a` is the symbol `print`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the arguments to a macro haven't been evaluated when the macro
is invoked.

When you invoke your macro like this:

> (te print 2 inc 4)

The parameters are bound to the following:

- a: `'print`
- b: `'2`
- c: `'(inc 4)` (because the macro is variadic any parameters past the first two are put
  into a list in `c`)

The expression you end up with is this:

> `(print ~('print '2 '(inc 4)))

Here's the problem: that inner `print` is *not* the same thing as the function
`clojure.core/print`. This is a macro, so it's an unevaluated symbol. You're using
the symbol itself as a function in this case, instead of using the function referred
to by the symbol.

Every symbol in Clojure is a function that looks itself up in a map.
That lookup takes two
parameters, a key and a default value. In this case the symbol `print` is trying to look
itself up in 2. Since 2 is not a map, it's returning the default value of `(inc 4)`.

Recall that unquote (`~`) means evaluate the expression and substitue the result
into the code generated by the macro.

So the compiler evaluates: `('print '2 '(inc 4))` which returns `(inc 4)` and then
substitutes that into the original expression.

That's how you end up with `(clojure.core/print (inc 4))`

Try this:

> (macroexpand-1 '(te blarg 2 inc 4))

You get exactly the same result even
though `blarg` isn't a variable that's defined anywhere in Clojure.

In your other example, the other answer is quite right. If you the third argument to your macro is not a function, then you'll get another error there.

Honestly, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish so I'm not sure if this really answers your question. But this is why you're seeing what you're seeing.